# How do I extrude faces inwards without creating bad geometry on the outside

Tags: geometry, extrude

I want to create a stair-like feature on the roof. To do this I have been using loop cuts and extrude to build out the stairs. However I encounter numerous problems each time. 1. is the outside which leaves gaping hole that I am not particularly fond of. I've read that you can stop this from happening by giving it thickness but if I use the solidify modifier it still has the exact same problem and causes even more issues.

[image]
As you can see it is working but it is forming small squares as a result of the extrusions. These squares overlap on the other side as you can see below. So I guess that is my main problem currently that I cannot find a solution to. It also overlaps on the top which is a major pain meaning i cant just delete the faces as it will delete the entire top of my model.
[image]
[image]
Maybe I'm stupid but I don't care any answers would be a help as I've spent far too much time on this as it is. Perhaps there is a completely different way to create what I'm trying to create here.

Comment: Close the top area by filling it with a face. Then use the _Inset Tool_ by pressing I, then E to extrude upwards. To get the steps in even sizes, enter values to to this. For example, press I then 0.1 and Return to inset 10 cm. Then E, 0.1, Return to extrude 10 cm.

Comment: Ditto of @GordonBrinkmann, should add this with screenshots as an answer.

Comment: @TheLabCat No time atm, I won't mind anybody else doing that... or maybe I'll do it later.

Comment: Still some issues with that. I presume you mean once i inset it i should extrude it upwards and that works fine but problem is I only need it to affect 2 sides of the room (+ the little bevel bit). I know i can use boundary for the open side but what about the right side.